# Countless warnings with SDL/OpenGL on OS X when dynamic graphics device switching is active

Tags: macos, opengl, intel, nvidia

On Snow Leopard with a macbook pro that has two graphics devices the following error is printed to stderr multiple times a second:

```
Wed Oct  6 02:35:27 nausicaa.local TestApp[92464] <Warning>:
CGDisplayIsCaptured: Fixing up display ID 0x4272ec2 for offline
mux head to 0x4272ec0
```

When I force the graphics device to be either Nvidia or Intel it works as expected.

Does anyone know how I can deal with that problem?  I suppose I could probably just force the graphics device to switch before OpenGL initializes, but neither do I know a reliable way that does that, nor does it sound like a particular good solution.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something that needs to be fixed in SDL itself. As far as I can tell, CGDisplayIsCaptured is complaining that the display ID SDL most likely got before the graphics switch is no longer technically valid, even though CGDisplayIsCaptured understands what SDL wants. Unfortunately, that information doesn't actually solve your problem.